# ThreeJS: Putting a light inside a box for a glowing effect

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm trying to recreate this glowing box from Beat Saber in ThreeJS:

[image: Beat Saber blocks]

I started by creating a shape in Blender and exporting an OBJ. I've loaded it in Three, as just a geometry:

[image: My own recreation]

Next I needed some lighting. I tried using a RectAreaLight, positioned inside but facing outwards, and this works alright:

[image: light from within]

My problem is that, compared with the screenshot above, it doesn't really seem like it's glowing, it just looks like a bright white triangle on a red cube. I'm not sure how to get the light to "spill" outside, like in the screenshot. Maybe I need to use a different kind of light?

Comment: Seems you're looking for selective bloom: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=selec#webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom_selective. Examples of using: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/instancing-selective-bloom/7506?u=prisoner849, https://discourse.threejs.org/t/totentanz-selective-bloom/8329?u=prisoner849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what are you looking for is done usally by pixel shaders.
Take a look at *glow* and *bloom* shaders like:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom.html

Comment: Ah! That's perfect :) I knew there was some huge thing I was missing. I'm new to this 3D stuff. Thanks Mosè!